# When it comes to Intermolecular Forces, when the chain length of a molecule increases, is there more or stronger dispersion forces?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have been told by my highschool teacher that there are more dispersion forces rather than stronger.However, reading up on articles, I have discovered that some explain the increase in boiling point due to **stronger** dispersion forces. Please clarify if this is an important distinction, or the same thing.

Comment: Could you expand a little on what you mean by "more"? Let's say we have two chains and somehow measure the force(s) between them. We now add one atom to each chain. In what sense do you mean there are "more" dispersion forces now?

Comment: Or to put it another way when you say "more" are you breaking down the *total* force between the chains into a sum over contributions from atom pairs

Comment: If by adding atoms you change the size of  any dipole, or change the type of atom, and so change the polarisability, then the size of the dispersion force can increase or decrease. However, if neither of this happens  and you add more of the same type of atom,  the dispersion will increase just because there are more atoms.

Comment: The confusion here, I suspect, is between thinking about the *total* force between molecules and the *strength* of the force contributed by each part of the molecule. In bigger molecules, the individual components don't get stronger, but there are more components, making the total force larger.